# @Positive Annotation still taking negative value

Tags: java, spring, bean-validation

My @Positive annotation is still taking a negative value.

The code validating the field is

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Positive(message = "value must be positive and 2 digits")
@Digits(integer=2, fraction=0, message = "value must be positive and 2 digits whole number")
@Column(name = "add_user")
private int addUser;
```

the import I am using is

```
import javax.validation.constraints.Positive;
```

the dependencies I am using is

```
       <dependency>
                    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
                </dependency>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

the form field to display the error is

```
    <tr>
            <td><form:label path="addUser">Add User</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="addUser"/></td>
            <td style="color:red"> <form:errors path="addUser"/> </td>
        </tr>
```

the controller method is

```
@PostMapping("/addBrewery")
public ModelAndView addAnBrewery(ModelMap model, @Valid @ModelAttribute("brewerie") Breweries brewerie, BindingResult result) {

    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        System.out.println(result);
    return new ModelAndView("/addBrewery");
}

service.addAnBreweries(brewerie);
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/breweries");
}
```

Breweries object class is a JPA
the code for Breweries.java is the following, I have to remove the getters and setters due to the amount of code and lack of text in this question

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "breweries")
@SecondaryTable(name = "breweries_geocode", pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "brewery_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))

@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByName", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.name = :name"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddress1", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.address1 = :address1"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddress2", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.address2 = :address2"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCity", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.city = :city"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByState", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.state = :state"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCode", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.code = :code"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCountry", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.country = :country"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByPhone", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.phone = :phone"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByWebsite", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.website = :website"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByImage", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.image = :image"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddUser", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.addUser = :addUser"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByLastMod", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.lastMod = :lastMod"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCreditLimit", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.creditLimit = :creditLimit"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByEmail", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.email = :email")})
public class Breweries implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Positive(message = "value must be positive")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotBlank(message = " field cannot be empty")

    @Size(min = 1, max = 50, message = "must be 50 characters or less")
    private String name;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50, message = "must be 50 characters or less")
    @Column(name = "address1")
    private String address1;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50, message = "must be 50 characters or less")
    @Column(name = "address2")
    private String address2;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 30, message = "must be 30 characters or less")
    @Column(name = "city")
    private String city;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 20, message = "must be 20 characters or less")
    @Column(name = "state")
    private String state;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
     //@Size(min = 1, max = 5, message = "must be 5 digits or less")
    @NotBlank(message = " field cannot be empty")
    @Pattern(regexp="\\d{1,5}", message = "must be 5 digits or less")
    //@digit
    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @Basic(optional = false)
     @NotNull()

    @Column(name = "country")
    @NotBlank(message = " field cannot be empty")
    private String country;
    // @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull()
    @NotBlank(message = " field cannot be empty")
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @URL( message = "must be a valid url")
    @NotBlank(message = " this field cannot be blank")
    @Column(name = "website")
    private String website;
    @Basic(optional = false)
   // @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @NotBlank(message = " this field cannot be blank")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Positive(message = "value must be positive and 2 digits")

   // @Digits(integer=2, fraction=0, message = "value must be positive and 2 digits whole number")
    @Column(name = "add_user")
    private int addUser;
    @Basic(optional = false)
//    @NotNull
    @Past()
    @Column(name = "last_mod")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastMod;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Digits(integer = 6, fraction = 2, message = "Must have a max of 6 digits before the decimal point and 2 afterwards.")
    @Column(name = "credit_limit")
    private double creditLimit;
   // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    //@Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @NotBlank(message = " this field cannot be blank")
    @Column(name = "email")
   @Email(message= " this is not a valid email adress")
    private String email;
    @Column(table = "breweries_geocode")
    @NotNull
    //@Size(min = -90, max = 90, message = "latitide must be between -90 and 90")
    @Max(value = 90, message = "latitide must be between -90 and 90")
    @Min(value = -90, message = "latitide must be between -90 and 90")
    private float latitude;
     @NotNull
    @Column(table = "breweries_geocode")
   // @Size(min = -180, max = 180, message = "latitide must be between -180 and 180")
      @Max(value = 80, message = "latitide must be between -180 and 80")
    @Min(value = -180, message = "latitide must be between -180 and 80")
    private float longitude;




    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Breweries)) {
            return false;
        }
        Breweries other = (Breweries) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "lit.sd4.model.Breweries[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }

}
```

Comment: pls show sources of models and your controller method (if you're using spring mvc in this case)

Comment: @amseager I have added what you were looking for i think

Comment: `addUser` is a part of `Breweries` or not? Can you show source code of
 `Breweries` and it's inner complex types if they exist.

Comment: @amseager addUser is apart of Breweries, Breweries is a jpa and i have added the code, except for the getters and setters and constructer due to how much code in the question and lack of text

Comment: There is an [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1376), so try to upgrade hibernate-validator version to 6.1.2.Final as annotation processor. It worked for me in this way.

Comment: @slesh thanks for the advice but that still doesn't fix the issue

Comment: Really strange. Try to replace `@Positive` with `@Min(value = 0)`

Comment: @slesh ya that works, I might come back to it later and try to figure it out

Comment: If you will have figure out the root cause, please don't forget to describe it here. I bet on that problem in versions of dependencies. Btw, could you please mark my reply as answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few notes:

1. Afaik `validation-api` is just an API i.e. set of annotations/interfaces. To get it to work you have to add validation API implementation, e.g. hibernate-validator, hibernate-validator-annotation-processor. Also, you have to configure Validator and inject it somehow into your app manually, by AOP or another way depending on your current project set up.
2. There is an [issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HV-1376), so try to upgrade hibernate-validator version to 6.1.2.Final as annotation processor. It worked for me in this way.
3. Try to replace `@Positive` with `@Min(value = 0)`

Comment: i am using those dependencies and i am injecting it into my code, ive gotten all the other annotations to work except this one, i have edited my question and added more code